# How do I include stb_image.h into my C++ project with Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to make a project that uses the `stb_image.h` library that is currently sitting in my `/home/user/libs/stb` folder.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(project_name)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_library(STB_LIB stb_image.h PATHS "/home/user/libs/stb/stb_image.h")
message("${STB_LIB}")

add_executable(project_name src/main.cpp)
```

The message I get is just `STB_LIB-NOTFOUND`, but I'm not sure what I would do if it did find the library.  I would imagine I would want to do something regarding a target, but I could really appreciate some guidance here.  I've looked around similar questions but I haven't seen one as simple as just letting me do:

```c
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
```

in my `main.cpp` file.

Comment: Just add include directory containing the header you want to include: `include_directory("/home/user/libs/stb")`.

Comment: Yep that did it, thanks!  Feel free to write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The right command is `include_directories`